# Use a local dependency (installed via mvn install) in a gradle project

Tags: gradle

Any ideas why my java source cannot use classes from the dependency declared in `build.gradle`?

Project structure ..

[image: project]

This is `Person.java`, where the error exists `World cannot be resolved to a type` ..

```
package org.gradle;

import org.apache.commons.collections.list.GrowthList;

public class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        new GrowthList();

        new World(); // World cannot be resolved to a type
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile 'org.jbox2d:jbox2d-library:2.3.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}
```

Filesystem ..

```
rob@work:~/.m2/repository/org/jbox2d/jbox2d-library/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT$ ls
jbox2d-library-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  jbox2d-library-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT.pom  m2e-lastUpdated.properties  maven-metadata-local.xml
```

When I try to run `compileJava` task ..

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      compileJava
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
/home/rob/workspaceMarsM6/Tes/src/main/java/org/gradle/Person.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        new World();
            ^
  symbol:   class World
  location: class Person
1 error
1 warning
 FAILED
```

Comment: Where does the `World` class exist?

Comment: its a class inside `jbox2d-library-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: You are not importing it in your `Person` class... or is it just not shown here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted issue by doing 1 of the following ..

```
Gradle -> refresh dependencies
```

or

```
restart eclipse
```